# Sqlite and Firefox, any security issues?

Tags: sqlite, security, firefox-addon

I am just starting out with Sqlite and have a couple questions about security?

1. What is the best method to secure it?
2. I see firefox has a plugin to access the database, isn't this a security issue? I don't want anyone seeing the database.

Thanks!

Comment: As long as it's on the client side, it's 100% readable by the user. The only kind of protection here is from other websites, so no web pages from other domains can read your data (same as for localStorage for example)

Comment: An important security concern with embedded SQL in any context is binding your parameters.  ( See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage#Binding_parameters )  Never pass strings made via concatenation for interpretation as SQL.